# How to break two variables that address to the same list in Python

Tags: python

For example:

```
Positives=negatives=[]

If True:
     Positives += [number]
else:
   Negatives += [number]
```

Now this part of code actually breaks the list into two others. But why the method append which does exactly the same doesn't work,and just puts objects in the same list?

Comment: This code does not work at all because `number` is not defined. There is no output and no specification of the desired output. `If True` is pointless. Please post a proper [MCVE].

Comment: your problem is the the first line, you assigne the same empty list to both positives and negatives

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the same list to them in the first place.  The `+=` operator modifies the list in place, so both your variables still refer to the same list which is updated.

You should do one of the following:

a) create two separate lists

```
Positives = []
Negatives = []

If True:
    Positives += [number]
else:
    Negatives += [number]
```

or b) use `+` instead of `+=` (which creates a new list)

```
Positives = Negatives = []

If True:
    Positives = Positives + [number]
else:
    Negatives = Negatives + [number]
```